# Add Parts to Model - Like Lightbars

Tags: materials

I need help
I have never tried it

It's about adding 3 objects as in the picture
but in Blender and not as Object children

http://www.emergency-planet.com/topic/22590-add-parts-to-model/

http://www.emergency-planet.com/uploads/monthly_2018_11/5c00415d9fd61_Namnls.jpg.646d9efaa2c57d415d6d24451e789987.jpg

Comment: I think what you need is to position each object and select all then Ctrl+J to join them together into a single mesh. You can undo this sort of join by selecting all vertices in Edit mode and Separating Loose Objects.

Comment: Well I can do that but the Ambulance textures is gone when I m in the game only Lightbars have textures

Comment: Other than parenting that is the only way you will get the meshes together. Once you have Joined the Meshes together you can create a new UV by unwrapping the joined meshes and then Baking the visible textures. Google Blender Bake

Comment: Can you show me how exacly do this

Comment: see the Workflow section at the end of this page https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/bake.html

Comment: Here is what I mean

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123961/textures-missing-on-my-model-when-joined-lightbars